# Route cURL requests through Tor network

Tags: tor

Say, I need to periodically access OtherSite.com/myfile.xml and I want to automate downloading it via the [Tor network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)).

Can I somehow route requests sent by cURL through the Tor network without opening a browser?

Comment: If you run Tor locally, you can use `curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 http://othersite.com/myfile.xml` which will use Tor to proxy the request and resolve DNS names over Tor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `torify`.

As per https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify:

> torify is a simple wrapper that attempts to find the best underlying
>   Tor wrapper available on a system. It calls torsocks or tsocks with a
>   tor specific configuration file.

`torify curl OtherSite.com/myfile.xml`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [torsocks](https://github.com/dgoulet/torsocks):

```
torsocks curl OtherSite.com/myfile.xml
```